# Using std::atomic to implement a lockfree structure, Dtor crashes

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, destructor, atomic

I'm refering to cppreference sample of std::atomic, trying to add a Dtor function for stack:

```
  #include<atomic>
  template<class T>
  struct node{
      T data;
      node* next;
      node(const T&data):data(data),next(nullptr){}
  };  
  template<class T>
  class stack{
      std::atomic<node<T>*> head;
  public: 
      void push(const T&data)
      {   
      node<T>* new_node=new node<T>(data);
      new_node->next=head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
      while(!std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(
                  &head,
                  &new_node->next,
                  new_node,
                  std::memory_order_release,
                  std::memory_order_relaxed));
      }   
      ~stack()
      {   
      node<T>* p=head;
      while(p)
      {
          node<T>* next=p->next;
          delete p;                                                         
          p=next;
      }
      }
  };  

  int main() 
  {
      stack<int> s;
      s.push(1);
      s.push(2);
      s.push(3);
      return 0;
  }
```

When the program executes till ~stack，the last delete function prompts crash, like below:

```
$ g++ myatomic.cpp -std=c++11
$ ./a.out
*** Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400b00 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7f07173a2725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x1a8)[0x7f07173aec18]
./a.out[0x4008f5]
./a.out[0x400829]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f071734b830]
./a.out[0x4006d9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2506641                            /home/x/cpp/x01/a.out
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:01 2506641                            /home/x/cpp/x01/a.out
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 2506641                            /home/x/cpp/x01/a.out
022f6000-02328000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f0717022000-7f071712a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2102313                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f071712a000-7f0717329000 ---p 00108000 08:01 2102313                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f0717329000-7f071732a000 r--p 00107000 08:01 2102313                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f071732a000-7f071732b000 rw-p 00108000 08:01 2102313                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f071732b000-7f07174eb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2102243                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f07174eb000-7f07176ea000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 2102243                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f07176ea000-7f07176ee000 r--p 001bf000 08:01 2102243                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f07176ee000-7f07176f0000 rw-p 001c3000 08:01 2102243                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f07176f0000-7f07176f4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f07176f4000-7f071770a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2102281                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f071770a000-7f0717909000 ---p 00016000 08:01 2102281                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f0717909000-7f071790a000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 2102281                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f071790a000-7f0717a7c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1312401                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f0717a7c000-7f0717c7c000 ---p 00172000 08:01 1312401                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f0717c7c000-7f0717c86000 r--p 00172000 08:01 1312401                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f0717c86000-7f0717c88000 rw-p 0017c000 08:01 1312401                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f0717c88000-7f0717c8c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0717c8c000-7f0717cb2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2102215                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f0717e8e000-7f0717e93000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0717eae000-7f0717eb1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0717eb1000-7f0717eb2000 r--p 00025000 08:01 2102215                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f0717eb2000-7f0717eb3000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 2102215                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f0717eb3000-7f0717eb4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffec8e19000-7ffec8e3a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffec8edb000-7ffec8edd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffec8edd000-7ffec8edf000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Terminated
```

I tried to gdb it, and the 3rd time of delete crashes. Is there anything wrong in my program?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `head` member of `stack` is never initialized, so your program has undefined behaviour, which just happens to manifest by the pointer being non-null and some garbage memory being deleted.

Fix this by initialising `head` in the constructor for `stack`:

```
stack() : head(nullptr){}
```

Comment: Lucky that it crashed. On my machine, my refrigerator explodes!

Comment: @erip Mine freezes. I suppose I should be happy about it.